# Swift: change pin color in didSelect view: MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I'm trying to change pin color in `didSelect view: MKAnnotationView`:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,
             didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    let selectedAnnotation = view.annotation as? MKPointAnnotation //ColorPointAnnotation
    //self.textField.text = selectedAnnotation!.title
    preferredSpot = selectedAnnotation!.title!
    view.tintColor = UIColor.green
}
```

But it's not changed when I tap on a pin - remains red. Does anybody know why and/or how to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pinTintColor` instead of `tintColor`

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let view = view as? MKPinAnnotationView {
        view.pinTintColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The delegate function is:

```
optional func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, 
        didSelect view: MKAnnotationView)
```

Comment: I changed to MKAnnotationView and tintColor but it doesn't help, it becomes bigger but remains red

Comment: @ElenaRubilova you need to cast your MKAnnotationView to MKPinAnnotationView, you can follow Kosuke answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Since pin tint is now deprecated, I thought I'd share my updated version based on Kosuke's answer with markerTint.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let view = view as? MKMarkerAnnotationView {
        view.markerTintColor = UIColor.systemBlue
    }
}
```